# How to Store and Capture Camera Images

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm attempting to develop a camera app for Windows 8 using C#.

My code:

```
public string newFilename { get; set; }
private StorageFile photo;
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    t1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
    CameraCaptureUI cam = new CameraCaptureUI();
    cam.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(6, 4);
    var photo = await cam.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

    //StorageFile photo = await cam.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    //if (photo != null)
    //{
    //    var targetFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("IMAGE11.jpg");
    //    if (targetFile != null)
    //    {
    //        await photo.MoveAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);
    //    }
    //}

    if (photo != null)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite));
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        im1.Source = bitmap;
        //StorageFile sample = await localfolder.CreateFileAsync("img.png", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    }
}

private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (photo != null)
    {
        await photo.MoveAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder,newFilename);
    }
}
```

My app shows the captured camera image.

My question is: **How can I store the captured camera images in a local folder?**

Comment: Well, what's the problem with the commented out lines you've tried?

Comment: So, you want to save a BitmapImage to a file.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161359/save-bitmapimage-to-file

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/40b76a69-4f94-4622-b928-5f31c7cfb98b/saving-bitmapimage-to-file) may be of use to you. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423565/how-do-i-take-a-bitmap-image-and-save-as-a-jpeg-image-file-on-a-windows-phone-7)